# PHP CLI - something like $PATH

Tags: path, filepath, php

I want to ask you if there is something like UNIX $PATH for PHP CLI.

Eg., I want to use

```
php a2addvhost.php example.com
```

instead of

```
php /usr/share/php/a2addvhost.php example.com
```

I tried to change include_path and $PATH but either work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're doing

```
php a2addvhost.php example.com
```

You're still in Unix. So the `a2addvhost.php` file must be in the current directory for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument must be the exact pathname. However, you can make a start script (as root):

```
$ echo -e '#!/bin/sh\nexec php /usr/share/php/a2addvhost.php "$@"\n' \
   > /usr/bin/a2addvhost
$ # And then start with ...
$ a2addvhost example.com
```

---

Alternatively, make `a2addvhost.php` executable by prepending it as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
/* php code goes here */
```

and making it executable:

```
$ chmod a+x /usr/share/php/a2addvhost.php
```

Now, if PATH contains  `/usr/share/php/`, you can start your script with

```
$ /usr/share/php/a2addvhost.php example.com
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, please check comment under Maerlyn's post

Comment: @GRoNGoR If it's not trivial, you should probably ask a new question about that. My first solution (before the line) does not require PATH modification, you just write a new file to `/usr/bin` (or `/usr/local/bin`). Also note that you have to `export PATH` after that to take any effect, and there's no sense in deciding between root and non-root if you're gonna do the same thing anyway.

Comment: I don't understand to the first line of your solution ... I need to use that for each file I want to execute like that, right ? (if yes, then I don't want to use that) ... and yes I know that I have to export the PATH - I simply edited the /etc/profile so it should work, but it doesn't ... I'm going to create a new question for that

Comment: You do not need to use that, but it makes the usage more comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

Add `/usr/share/php/` to your PATH, give it the executable flag, then simply run

```
a2addvhost.php example.com
```

you may need to add the shebang at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I now have problem with altering my $PATH ... this is what I have in /etc/profile:

if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
 PATH=".....:/usr/share/php"
else
 PATH=".....:/usr/share/php"
fi
export PATH

But this works only for normal user, not for root (It gets overridden somewhere ?) ... I use Debian by the way.

Comment: I checked it and it is just full of commented rows - nothing that can cahnge the $PATH